# Set up html bases pages phonegap

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova

I am setting up phonegap and I'd like to know the best practice to make a standard index.html, something like include header, include content and include body.
Otherwise Do I should repeat in every page doctype, css, js, etc. ?  Is it a good thing ?

Maybe with .load javascript can I do anything ?

I would like to know others useful advise to make app with phonegap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it is a best practice to use one html file. This helps achieve a native feel to your application. If you use multiple pages, items like the header, menus, footer will reload each time a new page is loaded and you loose the native feel.

I usually do something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  //load css js and meta tags
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    //header stuff here
    </header>
    <div id="views">
      <div id="main_view" class="view">
      //first 'page' content
      </div>
      <div id="another_view" class="view">
      //another 'page' content
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    //footer contents here
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in CSS set

```
.view { display: none; }
```

And use the id's of the div to show different 'page' content

```
#main_view { display: block; }
```